# Maven cannot build project with Qute templates

Tags: maven, quarkus

I've my Qute template under:
`src/main/resources/templates/myfile.html`

When I let IntelliJ execute the following mvn commando:
`mvn clean package`

I get a build error that the resource 'myfile' cannot be found. And when I manually copy the template folder into:
`target/classes`

and than do:
`mvn package`

Then the build works and I get no error.

Am I the only one having this problem ?

Btw, Im using:

- JDK 11 & Maven 3.6.x
- Linux (Ubuntu 18.04 based distro)
- Quarkus 1.1.1.final
- IntelliJ

Comment: Did you mean `src/main/resources/templates/myfile.html`?

Comment: yes sorry, was a typo. But this doesn't solve the problem.