# Quarkus Qute Can't resolve template

Tags: java, quarkus

I'm having trouble getting templates to resolve in Quarkus version `1.2.0.FINAL`. I'm following the guides ([here (quarkus.io)](https://quarkus.io/guides/qute-reference)), and as far as I can tell I have everything set up correctly. I really would like to have more to put for this but there doesn't seem to be much to try here (it seems like it should be super straight forward). I'm using Gradle to run my builds, if that matters.

Qute dependencies:

```
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-qute'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-qute'
```

Code:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class LifecycleBean {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LifecycleBean.class);

    private ZonedDateTime startDateTime;
    private ZonedDateTime endDateTime;

//    @Inject
    @ResourcePath("startTemplate")
    Template startTemplate;

    ...
}
```

I have a template file located at: `src/main/resources/templates/startTemplate.txt`

Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No template found for com.gjs.taskTimekeeper.webServer.server.LifecycleBean#startTemplate
```

Comment: Please share more info as am using same version with gradle and kotlin and can resolve template using `@ResourcePath`

Comment: What more info is there to put? As far as I'm aware, this is the entirety of the setup for qute templates

Comment: This may relate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59823216/maven-cannot-build-project-with-qute-templates?r=SearchResults&s=2|83.0820

Comment: Try to copy your templates folder manually to /target/classes folder and then run mvn package (without clean).

Comment: I don't have a target, but in build it looks like the templates are copied over just fine

Answer (score 0):

This issue was eventually fixed, https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/7156